# Change the color of line in buffer using Vim+Python

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I'm using Vim python for writing a plugin, I want to know how I can change the color of line number based on `vim.buffers` from the vim module and also execute commands specific to the buffer. I skimmed through the documentation and tried to find the methods to execute commands specific to a buffer but couldn't find it.

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Highlighting is not buffer-local, it's global. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vim there is no one solution... but I think this is a very simple solution.

```
function! Testing_Highlight()
    highlight MyPattern ctermbg=red ctermfg=blue

    python << EOF
    from vim import *

    myline = 4

    eval("matchadd('MyPattern', '\%" + str(myline) + "l', 100)")
    EOF
endfunction
```